# c stringification and __function__

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to add a c macro which compiles a local variable
which is initialized to the function name..

for example.

```
 void foo (void)
 {
 stubmacro;
 }


 void bar (void)
 {
 stubmacro;
 }
```

would essentially compile as:

```
 void foo (void)
 {
 char*function_name="foo";
 }


 void bar (void)
 {
 char*function_name="bar";
 }
```

I've always had a difficult time with C preprocessor macros,
 especially when it comes to stringification

the macro uses the prefined **FUNCTION** ..

```
#define stubmacro char*function_name=##_FUNCTION__
```

Anyway, my stubmacro macro is wrong, and I' would love some help
 on it

Comment: "...my stubmacro macro is wrong..." You may want to clarify that for people reading your question. And you should really used `const char *` if you're assigning directly to a pointer regardless. Finally, `__FUNCTION__` is already a quoted string literal, so I'm not sure what you're trying to stringify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define stubmacro char *func = __func__;

void foo (void)
{
    stubmacro;
    printf("foo = %s\n", func);
}

void bar (void)
{
    stubmacro;
    printf("bar = %s\n", func);
}

int main(void)
{
    foo();
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

The output would be:

```
foo = foo
bar = bar
```

Here `__func__` is a macro that will be replaced with the function name in which it is used

Also instead using a macro for the function name you can directly print in the function like below

```
void foo (void)
{
    printf("foo = %s\n", __func__);
}
```

Comment: Why would you do that? This is way too complicated, just use `__func__` no need to declare anything.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Yeah that is the best way to do. But since the OP asked that he wanted a macro, I used the macro. Also updated my answer based on your comment

Answer (score 4):

Just use `__func__`, this is a predefined string that does what you need:

> The identifier `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the
>   translator as if, immediately following the opening brace of each
>   function definition, the declaration

```
static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
```

> appeared, where function-name is the name of the
>   lexically-enclosing function.